# How to get redirected url from RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, url, redirect, resttemplate

I would like to call RestTemplate with http GET and retrieve status code and redirected url (if there was one).

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create Apache `HttpClient` with custom `RedirectStrategy` where you can intercept intermediate response(s) when redirect occurred.
2. Replace default request factory with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and new Apache `HttpClient`.

Have a look at [org.apache.http.client.RedirectStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/RedirectStrategy.html) for more information. Or reuse `DefaultRedirectStrategy` as in the following example:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
        .create()
        .setRedirectStrategy( new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {

            @Override
            public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
                    HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {

                System.out.println(response);

                // If redirect intercept intermediate response.
                if (super.isRedirected(request, response, context)){
                    int statusCode  = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    String redirectURL = response.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue();
                    System.out.println("redirectURL: " + redirectURL);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        })
        .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
.......
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Spring and overriding prepareConnection() in SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory...

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate( new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory(){
    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection( HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod ) {
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    }
} );

ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange( "url", HttpMethod.GET, null, Object.class );
int statusCode = response.getStatusCodeValue();
String location = response.getHeaders().getLocation() == null ? "" : response.getHeaders().getLocation().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("someurl", HttpMethod.GET, null, Object.class);
HttpHeaders headers = responseEntity.getHeaders();
URI location = headers.getLocation();
location.toString();
```

Comment: This does not work. RestTemplate will follow the redirect.

Comment: Not with the default httpclient, I think.